# Animating constraint results in different initial position

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

I have a green view, which is pinned to the edges of the top view. On top is a blue view, which is also a child of the top view and which is aligned using the following code...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.leftAnchor).isActive = true

        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let top = blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.topAnchor)
        top.priority = 800
        top.isActive = true

        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {

            let bottom = self.blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.greenView.bottomAnchor)
            bottom.priority = 1000
            bottom.isActive = true

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the animation code, this is how it looks...

[image]

With the animation block, the blue view finishes in the correct place, but it starts at the top of the screen instead of aligned to the top of the green view.

[image]

Why is the animation block causing the blue view to start further up the screen?

Comment: Based on your code, you are setting `Blue` to be the same size and position of `Green` ... then the animation block slides `Blue` down until it is completely off the screen. Is that what you are seeing? Is that not what you want?

Comment: That's what I want and mostly what it's doing. The problem is that the animation seems to be causing the blue to start at the top of the screen instead of at the same position as green.

Answer (score 1):

OK - the Blue view is not starting at the top of the Green view because you are starting your animation *before* the initial layout has finished.

You could move the animation block into a function triggered after a delay, or into `viewDidAppear`:

```
import UIKit

class AnimViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.leftAnchor).isActive = true

        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let top = blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.topAnchor)
        top.priority = 800
        top.isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {

            let bottom = self.blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.greenView.bottomAnchor)
            bottom.priority = 1000
            bottom.isActive = true

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way of forcing an update before starting the animation?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is very early in the order of activities for  view controller. `viewDidAppear` is a perfectly suitable place to start a 5-second animation.

Comment: What if you wanted to have all of this code on a click handler, for example? You're suggesting that a delay would need to be added?

Comment: No... when you load and display a View Controller, lots of stuff has to happen. `viewDidLoad` is ***early*** in the process, and the subviews, gestures, constraints, etc have not been fully "worked out" by the OS. You have `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` `viewWillLayoutSubviews` `viewDidLayoutSubviews` `viewDidAppear` etc. Acting on a Button tap is a totally different situation - you are acting on objects that are already there (unless you mean button-tap loads a new controller, in which case see previous comments).

Comment: Yes, animation issues with dynamically added view controllers is exactly what's been causing problems. Sorry, but which previous comments do you mean?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself, because you are certainly confusing me. Is there a reason you don't want to start the animation in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Yeah, because my animation, which includes adding view controllers, is triggered by a notification handler. I set it up the code as it is in this question as a sanity check. The real code does very strange things.

Comment: ... but even this sanity check has this odd artifact that the question is about.

Comment: Not trying to sound like a (whatever), but... If you are putting animation code in one place, and it does very strange things, then it seems pretty obvious you have put it in the wrong place. Not sure what visual effect you are going for, if you want your animation to start ***before the view is visible***?

Comment: I want to create a view controller, position it with auto layout and then animate it to a new position, all in the same handler.

Comment: Do you want to load a view and position/animate it as a subview of the current view? Or, load a controller as a child VC and position/animate *its* view as a subview of the current view? Or do you want to animate a transition from one view controller to another?

Comment: The last one. I'm trying to slide in or out a login view controller. The transition works fine with a simple cross fade but with auto layout for initial position + animation, it's behaving even more strangely than the artefact from this question. The difference is perhaps that the view controller to appear is added dynamically.

Comment: Well, I fixed it by setting up the view controllers in the storyboard and not adding them in code at runtime.